# Rails Polymorphic association + fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphism

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to set up this schema with polymorphic associations:

a "Document" has one metadata object, but this can either be "PDFMetaData" or "TXTMetaData".

My concerns are:

To set up this association, I can do this

```
class Document
  belongs_to :metadata, :polymorphic => true
end

class PDFMetaData
  has_one :document, :as => :metadata
end

class TXTMetaData
  has_one :document, :as => :metadata
end
```

This works, but it kind of feels like reverse for me: A document has_one metadata object, not opposite?

Also, I'm really running into problems when trying to create a nested form for my new document. I know I can use fields_for, but how do I know what kind of object it is? (PDFMetaData or TXTMetaData). Do I have to render separate partials depending on what kind of document I have?

I'm afraid that the latter ties in with my first question, and that I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can see where you're coming from about the confusion with arrangement of belongs_to & has_one in this case, the rationale is based on where the foreign_key is in the DB schema. The documents table contains the foreign_key that relates it to the PdfMetaData object thus it wouldn't make sense to describe the relationship the other way round since there would be no way to have a has_many relationship (how would you store multiple foreign keys in the 1 database row?)

Hopefully that makes sense ... but on to the 2nd problem, the solution depends on the list of valid attributes on your `TXTMetaData` and `PDFMetaData` classes. If they have the same attributes (or at least the ones you want available in your form are the same) then you should be okay with

```
fields_for :metadata do |meta_fields|
  meta_fields.text_field :attr
  meta_fields.text_fields :attr2
end
```

and so on

If however you want to expose different attributes then I'd suggest detecting the class of your metadata object and act accordingly e.g.

```
meta_obj = document.metadata
fields_for :metadata, meta_obj do |meta_fields|
  if meta_obj.is_a?(PDFMetaData)
    meta_fields.text_field :attr
    meta_fields.text_fiels :attr2
  elsif meta_obj.is_a?(TXTMetaData)
    meta_fields.text_field :other_attr
    meta_fields.text_fiels :other_attr2
  end
end
```